# grep: gcov-tool.1.gz: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, grep, man

I am learning Unix at the moment. I am trying to search the manual pages for the words `column | chop`. I do:

```
cd /usr/share/man/man1
egrep -i 'column|chop' *
```

I get this result:

```
grep: gcov-tool.1.gz: No such file or directory
grep: i686-linux-gnu-gcov-tool.1.gz: No such file or directory
```

Please can someone tell me want am not doing right? I am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS on Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Comment: The errors are likely due to broken symbolic links. However you should use `zgrep` to search within compressed files e.g. `zgrep -iE 'column|chop' *`. Also consider using the keyword search facility of `man` itself e.g. `man -k column`

Comment: What's the output of `find /usr/share/man/man1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -xtype l -ls`?

Comment: @steeldriver Cheers for the reply. I did zgrep -iE 'column|chop' * Got no response

Comment: @Evan that's odd - on my 16.04 system I get 1373 matches. Are you sure you are in the `/usr/share/man/man1` directory?

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry for the delay.  Excuse me. My bad. I didn't cd to /usr/share/man/man1. Can't find zgrep on man page, though I think I got a little bit idea from info zgrep. I guess 'E' option means extended regular expression right?

Comment: @DavidFoerster. Cheers for the reply. Sorry for the delay. I got this:- 291592      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Apr 25 00:09 /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool.1.gz -> gcov-tool-5.1.gz
                                                                                                    291793      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Apr 25 00:09 /usr/share/man/man1/i686-linux-gnu-gcov-tool.1.gz -> gcov-tool-5.1.gz

Comment: more relevantly to David's question, an `ls -l /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool-5.1.gz` would prove the point that egrep is complaining about a broken symlink. Ditto the i686 message.

Comment: @DavidFoerster. Cheers mate. Note taken

Comment: @JeffSchaller. Cheers mate

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for your help so far mate. When I do `dpkg-query -S /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool-5.1-gz` I get this `dpkg-query : no path found matching pattern /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool-5.1-gz`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: How did you install GCC 5.1? What's the output of `dpkg-query -S /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool\*` and `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX update-alternatives --display gcov-tool`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've not installed GCC 5.1, at least knowingly. Output of `dpkg-query -S /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool\*` is   `gcc: /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool.1.gz` Output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX update-alternatives --display gcov-tool` is `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcov-tool`. Please bear with me. Still trying to figure out how to go about formatting comments

Comment: @Evan: The best way to format comments is to [edit] your question instead. ;-] See my earlier comment for more advantages of adding new information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

`find -xtype l` matches broken symbolic links, so

```
$ find /usr/share/man/man1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -xtype l -ls
291592 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 25 00:09 /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool.1.gz -> gcov-tool-5.1.gz
291793 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 25 00:09 /usr/share/man/man1/i686-linux-gnu-gcov-tool.1.gz -> gcov-tool-5.1.gz
```

reveals that the ostensibly missing files, `gcov-tool.1.gz` and `i686-linux-gnu-gcov-tool.1.gz` are actually broken symbolic links to the missing file `gcov-tool-5.1.gz`.

In Ubuntu files in `/usr/share` are supposed to be managed by the package manager, so of you want that file back the easiest way would be to look up the package to whom the file belongs,

```
dpkg-query -S /usr/share/man/man1/gcov-tool-5.1.gz
```

and reinstall the matching package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall <PACKAGE>
```

(`gcov-tool-5.1` points to the `gcc-5` package of an outdated Ubuntu release.)